# Eliminar por completo bootstrap de laravel

Tags: laravel, bootstrap, laravel-5

Buenas me gustaría saber como puedo eliminar por completo bootstrap de un proyecto laravel. ya que, aunque en las vistas html tengo puesto otra hoja de estilos hacia normalize.css y no hay nada referente a bootstrap me sigue aplicando algunos estilos como fuentes etc... de bootstrap.

Pd: bootstrap aun sigue instalado en el proyecto laravel porque hay una carpeta con el nombre.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1 Elimina la dependencia en package.json, borrando su línea respectiva:

```
"devDependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.18",
    "bootstrap": "^4.0.0", <--- elimina esta línea
    "cross-env": "^5.1",
    "jquery": "^3.2",
    "laravel-mix": "^4.0.7",
    "lodash": "^4.17.5",
    "popper.js": "^1.12",
    "resolve-url-loader": "^2.3.1",
    "sass": "^1.15.2",
    "sass-loader": "^7.1.0",
    "vue": "^2.5.17"
}
```

En caso que desees asegurarte que no queda Bootstrap instalado, deberás eliminar la carpeta node_modules y ejecutar `npm run install`.

2 Elimina el archivo resources/js/bootstrap.js

3 Elimina la siguiente línea del archivo resources/js/app.js

```
require('./bootstrap');
```

No sé en dónde tengas una carpeta bootstrap relacionada con el frontend, en una instalación nueva de Laravel, no hay ninguna.